# Show that the trace of A is less than n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries such that $A^k=I_n$ for some positive integer $k$. Show that the trace of $A$ satisfies $$|tr(A)| \leq n.$$

I have no idea how to approach this question. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A^k=I$ means its minimal polynomial divides $x^k-1$ and thus has distinct roots.  The trace is the sum of those roots (the sum of the eigenvalues).  As roots of $x^k-1$ those are all roots of unity so lie on the unit circle in $\Bbb C$.  So you need to show that the sum of $n$ roots of unity is no bigger than $n$.  That's a sum of $n$ things on the unit circle in $\Bbb C$ so it's geometrically obvious that it cannot have absolute value greater than $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you expand your explanation on minimal polynomial and distinct roots please? I get how the min polynomial divides $x^k-1$. How does that lead to distinct roots? Sorry I'm new to min. polynomial.

Comment: $x^k-1$ has $k$ roots, they are mostly complex (not real), they are equally spaced around the unit circle in $\Bbb C$.  That's because when you multiply two complex numbers on the unit circle the product is on the unit circle as well, and it's the number you get simply by adding the angles.  That's why the roots of $x^k-1$ are equally spaced around the unit circle.  Do a google search on "cyclotomic polynomial" for more.